# Most Pythonic and fastest way to change a file name extension, if it's uppercase, to lower case

Tags: python

I have a list of files and some of them have upper case file name extensions, eg file.PDF. In these cases, i would like to change the upper case to lower case, eg file.pdf

I came up with this solution

```
currentDir = 'theDirectory'
for file in os.listdir(currentDir):
    print(file)
    if file[-3:] == 'PDF':
        oldName = currentDir+'/'+file
        newName = currentDir+'/'+file[:-3]+'pdf'
        os.rename( oldName ,  newName )
```

I'll be dealing with millions of files, daily, so it's important that it's the most efficient method possible.

Is there a better way than the solution above ?

Comment: You have an error on line 1

Comment: If you only ever have pdf files, this is fine. If you have other extensions, obviously this is not a good way.

Comment: If you want real efficiency, Python is not your best bet. If you want readability an maintainability, it's a reasonable choice

Comment: you can try threading module.

Comment: You can use **glob** and **pathlib** modules in Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want lowercase all of the extensions, not just 'PDF', or/and have some more control on renaming most simple, intuitive and self-descriptive base of solution is

```
def lowercase_exts(folder):
  for fname in os.listdir(folder):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    os.rename(os.path.join(folder, fname), os.path.join(folder, name + ext.lower()))
```

But if you need just efficiently rename millions of pdf on windows

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir(folder)
subprocess.call('ren *.PDF *.pdf', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work, making use of os.path.splitext().

```
currentDir = 'theDirectory'
for file in os.listdir(currentDir):
    print(file)
    newExt=os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower()
    oldName = currentDir+'/'+file
    newName = os.path.splitext(file)[0]+newExt
    os.rename( oldName ,  newName )
```

Comment: `oldName = os.path.join(currentDir, file)`

Comment: @thebjorn true, that is better. I was just modifying the line I needed to in the original code, though your suggestion is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with the `pathlib` library in Python 3

```
from pathlib import Path

dir_path = "C:/temp"
results = [x.rename(x.joinpath(x.parent,str(x.name).split(".")[0]+"."+str(x.name).split(".")[1].lower())) for x in Path(dir_path).iterdir() if x.is_file()]
```

Hope it helps.